# multiple file upload with paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, plugins

Is there a way to do multiple file upload in paperclip on rails 3.1? I have tried all possible including uploadify but is looks so complex. A brief example would be better?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no way around the complexity of uploadify and its ilk - doing multiple uploads is inherently a fairly complex thing to do.

Comment: @sscirrus thats not true. Check my answer...

Comment: @MohitJain - your nested forms railscast link is completely irrelevant to multiple file uploads, especially when compared to the ability of proper uploading facilities (like uploadify and others) that can upload files as they are attached, rather than trying to send all the data at once.

Comment: @sscirrus complex or not complex, it imagemagic and paperclip does not work om rails 3.1rc4.

Comment: very interesting, the bit about 3.1 I didn't know.

Comment: Are you asking about uploading more than 1 file at once, or multiple file types using the same model?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I particularly like [jQuery FileUpload UI](http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload). However, it's still not simple. Expect a struggle if you're not very familiar with Javascript and jQuery.